# Selenium executes parameterized tests in parallel in the same browser tab

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit5

I have parameterized test methods that I want to run in parallel. But when I execute my test class - I see that two browser tabs are opened but only one of them is used by tests to interact with page elements. And because of that all tests failed.

I think that the possible reason for this problem is that for some reason a new instance of Webdriver is not created for each execution of the test method.
How I can fix this problem?

Here is my code:

**DriverSingleton:**

```
public class DriverSingleton {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    private DriverSingleton() {}

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (null == driver) {
            switch (System.getProperty("browser")) {
                case "firefox": {
                    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                }
                case "edge": {
                    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
                    driver = new EdgeDriver();
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
                    options.addArguments("--headless");

                    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                }
            }
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public static void closeDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
            driver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

JunitConditions:

```
public class JunitConditions {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    public static LoginAction loginAction;
    public static SidebarAction sidebarAction;
    public static FiltersAction filtersAction;
    public static FiltersPage filtersPage;
    public static LaunchesAction launchesAction;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {

        System.out.println("Opening the browser");
        driver = DriverSingleton.getDriver();

        System.setProperty("env", "prod");

        loginAction = new LoginAction(driver);
        sidebarAction = new SidebarAction(driver);
        filtersAction = new FiltersAction(driver);
        launchesAction = new LaunchesAction(driver);

        filtersPage = new FiltersPage(driver);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void closeBrowser() {
        System.out.println("Closing the browser");
        DriverSingleton.closeDriver();

    }
}
```

JunitTest:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class JunitTest extends JunitConditions {

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class LaunchNameAndFailed {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @Execution(SAME_THREAD)
        @CsvSource({"Demo, 1, 4", "Demo, 6, 3", "Demo, 8, 3", "Demo, 9, 2"})
        @Description("Add filter: Launch name + Failed")
        public void setLaunchNameAndFailed(String launchName, String filterInput, int launchesAmountOutput) throws InterruptedException {
            loginAction.doLogin();
            sidebarAction.openLaunchesPage();
            filtersAction.activateFiltering();
            filtersAction.addLaunchNameFilter(launchName);
            filtersAction.addFilterFromDrpDwn("Failed", filterInput);
            launchesAction.countLaunchesAmount(launchName, launchesAmountOutput);
        }
    }

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class LaunchNameAndSkipped {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @Execution(CONCURRENT)
        @CsvSource({"Demo, 0, 5", "Demo, 1, 2", "Demo, 2, 1", "Demo, 3, 0"})
        @Description("Add Launch name + Skipped")
        public void setLaunchNameAndSkipped(String launchName, String filterInput, int launchesAmountOutput) throws InterruptedException {
            loginAction.doLogin();
            sidebarAction.openLaunchesPage();
            filtersAction.activateFiltering();
            filtersAction.addLaunchNameFilter(launchName);
            filtersAction.addFilterFromDrpDwn("Skipped", filterInput);
            launchesAction.countLaunchesAmount(launchName, launchesAmountOutput);
        }

    }

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class LaunchNameAndProductBug {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @Execution(CONCURRENT)
        @CsvSource({"Demo, 0, 5", "Demo, 1, 3", "Demo, 4, 2", "Demo, 5, 0"})
        @Description("Add Launch name + Product Bug")
        public void setLaunchNameAndProductBug(String launchName, String filterInput, int launchesAmountOutput) throws InterruptedException {
            loginAction.doLogin();
            sidebarAction.openLaunchesPage();
            filtersAction.activateFiltering();
            filtersAction.addLaunchNameFilter(launchName);
            filtersAction.addFilterFromDrpDwn("Product bug", filterInput);
            launchesAction.countLaunchesAmount(launchName, launchesAmountOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably can't control two tabs at the same time. (though you could try by getting the sessionID from the first launch, and using that with the second driver...it's a little hacky but it might work?)  You can, however, use 2 drivers each controlling a driver/browser pair in a separate thread.  (You wouldn't use a singleton in either case...)